# move a series of images with javascript

Tags: jquery, image

I have a simple html table with 5 images one next to the other from left to right.

I need to do this:

1) at the mouseover of an image it is replaced with another one that is the same image with a different color (ok, I think it is pretty simple and I'll try by myself)

2) when an image is clicked it moves to the left. For example, if I click the fourth image starting from left, this image moves to the first position and the ones that were on its left (image 1,2,3) shift one position to the right.

It would be better this effect to be nice to see and smooth. Do you think it is possible to do with javascript or I have to use Flash?

Thank you

Comment: css3 animations and jquery.animate() is what you need for smoother effects and for other hovering effects you can use css sprites if your images are small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its possible with JavaScript. Here's a very basic example to get you started.

```
<div id="images">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/110/110" data-replacement-image="http://baconmockup.com/110/110" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/120/120" data-replacement-image="http://baconmockup.com/120/120" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/130/130" data-replacement-image="http://baconmockup.com/130/130" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/140/140" data-replacement-image="http://baconmockup.com/140/140" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150" data-replacement-image="http://baconmockup.com/150/150" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("#images").on("mouseover", "img", function () {
        $(this).data("original-image", $(this).attr("src"));
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("replacement-image"));
    });
    $("#images").on("mouseout", "img", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("original-image"));
    });
    $("#images").on("click", "img", function () {
        $("#images").prepend($(this));
        $(this).mouseout();
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wd5Fz/1/

Comment: Nice. It works. Now I'd like to do this: when I click on one image, I need to change the image with another based on the one I clicked. Is it possible? I think I have to use something other..

Comment: Wonderful. And if I need an "original" image, a "mouseover" image and a third image that comes after the original has been clicked and moved? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Your original question asked if what you wanted was *possible* with JavaScript. I have answered question AND provided example code. If you have further requirements you should post a NEW question. It is inappropriate to extend this one via comments and besides, this question is on hold.